# I need to create a URL in swift with an encoded foreword slash in its path (without hierarchical significance)

Tags: swift, http, url

My URL is something like this: `https://domain.tld/path/question Thing1 / Thing2`

When encoded, I want my url to becmome `https://domain.tld/path/question%20Thing1%20%2f%20Thing2`

If i do

```swift
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "domain.tld"
components.path = "path/question Thing1 / Thing2"
```

the last foreword slash is not encoded, and the url becomes `https://domain.tld/path/question%20Thing1%20%/20Thing2`

if I do:

```swift
components.path = "path/question Thing1 %2f Thing2"
```

The url becomes `https://domain.tld/path/question%20Thing1%20%25%2f20Thing2`.

I understand why this happens, I just need a **swift** solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches. If you can easily compute the exact encoding by hand, then you can just use `percentEncodedPath`:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "domain.tld"
components.percentEncodedPath = "/path/question%20Thing1%20%2f%20Thing2"
```

Alternately, you can encode "all non-path characters + slash":

```
let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "/"))
let filePath = "question Thing1 / Thing2".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)!
```

And then append that:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "domain.tld"
components.path = "/path/"

components.percentEncodedPath += filePath
```

Or skip the components and make a string with the same `filePath`:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://domain.tld/path/\(filePath)")!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import Foundation
let base = "https://domain.tld/path/question"
let path = " Thing1 / Thing2t"
let encodedPath = path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
let urlString  = "\(base)\(encodedPath)"
print(urlString)
```

output:

```
https://domain.tld/path/Fquestion%20Thing1%20%2F%20Thing2t
```

Comment: I do not want the / after path and before question to be encoded

Comment: @KabirKwatra updated my answer. you need to understand the logic behind what I'm doing. Look closely at the path variable and the very next line encodedPath. I'm trying to encode everything which is inside the path variable. Like you said in the comment that you don't want to encode the slash after path and before question, therefore I moved it to base variable.